# Listview Subitems Forecolor

Tags: c#, listview, subitem

How to change `forecolor` for all subitems in `listview`.

I have 2 columns, I need column 1 white, and second (subitems) column gray color.

tried this after setting gray color from items & subitems UI,

```
listView1.Items[0].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
```

but not working for `items[1]`.

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Set the item.UseItemStyleForSubItems  = false __before__ setting the subitem's colors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked that code. It is working. I think it will work for you too.
A detail discussion is available in the given link. Thank you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
   listView1.Items[i].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
   listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
   listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
}
```

Addional Information: There is a very similar question is available on that link.
Please check the provided link: [How can I change the ForeColor of a single sub item in a ListView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576735/how-can-i-change-the-forecolor-of-a-single-sub-item-in-a-listview-control)